# Can not be able to redirect to 'password_change_done'

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-authentication

views.py:

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def password_change(request,
    template_name='password_change_form.html',
    password_change_form=PasswordChangeForm,):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student:password_change_done'))
    else:
        form = password_change_form(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': PasswordChangeForm,
        'title': _('Password change'),
        'current_app': 'student',
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)

@login_required
def password_change_done(request,
    template_name='password_change_done.html',):

    context = {
        'title': _('Password change successful'),
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^password_change/$', auth_views.password_change, {'template_name': 'password_change_form.html'}, name="password_change"),
    url(r'^password_change/done/$', auth_views.password_change_done, {'template_name': 'password_change_done.html'}, name="password_change_done"),
    url(r'^restricted/', views.restricted, name='restricted'),
    url(r'^mains/', views.mains, name = 'mains'),
]
```

My `'password_change'` form is working fine but when I'm click submit button it redirects me to the following url:- `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/stu/password_change/None'` inspite of `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/stu/password_change/done'` as expected according to my views and urls.

Is I'm doing wrong somewhere?

Please help me to get into it?

Thanks! in advance

Comment: Things are working fine once I added {'post_change_redirect' : '/path/to/url/',} in urls...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `login_required decorator` in your `password_change_done`
That means your user must be authenticated to access that view.
After changing the password you are no longer authenticated. In you `password_change` view you must authenticate and login your user after changing the password.